# efficient way to create JavaScript object from array of properties and array of matching property values

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, time-complexity

Is it possible to create the the `data1` array without using nested for loops?

```
// My starting Normalized data
var fields = ["name","age"];
var data2 = [["John",20],["Tom",25]]; 


// What I want the result to look like Denormalized
var data1 = [{"name":"John", "age":20},{"name":"Tom", "age":25}];


// My solution
var data1 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++){
   var temp = {};
   for(var y = 0; y < fields.length; y++){
      temp[fields[y]] = data2[i][y];
   }
   data1.push(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally thought of an efficient way that doesn't use nest for loops! :)

```
var fields = ["name","age"];
var data2 = [["John",20],["Tom",25]]; 
var body = "";

for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
   body = body.concat("this."+fields[i] +"=args["+i+"]; ");
}

var model = new Function("args",body);

var data1 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++){
   var x = new model(data2[i]);
   data1.push(x);
}
```

Comment: And it is really fragile...The most efficient way would be to do it on the server to start!

Comment: I bet this is slower than two loops and less efficient. `new Function` is not "cheap".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
var fields = ["name","age"];
var data2 = [["John",20],["Tom",25]]; 
var data1 = data2.map(function(arr){ 
   var obj = {};
   arr.forEach(function(val, ind){ obj[fields[ind]] = val; });
   return obj;
});
```

but it is basically nest loops.

Comment: check out my answer, it doesn't use nested for loops!

Answer (score 0):

Or you could start getting acquainted with Javascript tools like the underscore/lodash libraries that offer a lot of utilities functions for cases like this.

For example, using [_.zipObject()](https://lodash.com/docs#zipObject) offered by [lodash](https://lodash.com/):

```
fields = ["name", "age"];
data2 = [["John", 20],["Tom", 25]];
res = [];
data2.forEach(function(arr) {
    res.push(_.zipObject(fields, arr));
});
```

In essence as @epascarello mentioned, you are still doing a double loop.  It's just more elegant (subject always to coding taste) and more compact.

Answer (score 0):

No loops...

```
var data1 = [];
data1.push(eval('({"' + fields[0] + '":"' + data2[0][0] +
                '","' + fields[1] + '":' + data2[0][1] + '})'));
data1.push(eval('({"' + fields[0] + '":"' + data2[1][0] +
                '","' + fields[1] + '":' + data2[1][1] + '})'));
```

Guess it depends on your definition of efficient.

Comment: without a loop of some kind, it has to look similar to this.

Comment: i just didn't want nested for loops, I posted the answer. thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation using native map and reduce (which will be nested loops - but figured I'd throw it in as another option):

```
var data1 = data2.map(function(currentArray, index){
  return currentArray.reduce(function(objToReturn, currentValue, index){
    objToReturn[fields[index]] = currentValue;
    return objToReturn;
  },{});
});
```