# kendo ui Data Source - Schema - Parse function error when creating new Function inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I am using the following constructor create a new function:
`new Function("args", body);`

but in parse function it throwing the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifierkendo.data.DataSource.schema.parse @ KendoWorklist?processId=1:257g.extend.success @ kendo?v=eOyB53xLlSdFHOrBbggvVxenL4FmfrA-viibHS3DbGs1:1g.extend.read.i._queueRequest.i.online.i.transport.read.success @ kendo?v=eOyB53xLlSdFHOrBbggvVxenL4FmfrA-viibHS3DbGs1:1vt.extend.read.i.success @ kendo?v=eOyB53xLlSdFHOrBbggvVxenL4FmfrA-viibHS3DbGs1:1i.Callbacks.a @ jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1:1i.Callbacks.h.fireWith @ jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1:1k @ jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1:1i.ajaxTransport.send.u @ jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1:1
```

why would the new Function constructor not working in the parse function?

Comment: I'm lost with the question, what are you trying to do? can you give us more details

Comment: @cycopepe  
I'm trying to create a new function in the parse method like.... parse: function(response){ var x = new Function("args", body)}

Comment: @t-holland what is the reason to try to do that?

Comment: @cycopepe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707085/efficient-way-to-create-javascript-object-from-array-of-properties-and-array-of look at my answer to this question. I'm parsing normalized data to become denormalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If make the model outside the parse function of the schema, you can use it like this

```
   <script>
      var fields = ["fieldA","fieldB"];
      var body = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
       body += "this."+fields[i] +"=args["+i+"]; ";
    }
      var model = new Function("args",body);

    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      transport: {
        read: {
          url: "", //your url
          dataType: "jsonp"
        }
      },
      schema: {
        parse: function(response) {  
         var parsedresponse = [];    
          for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
             var x = new model(response[i]);   
             parsedresponse .push(prxduct);
          }

          return parsedresponse;
        }
      }
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: thank you! but I get the fields from the response object. I would have to call the data twice. I want to avoid it if possible but it may be the only way I'm really stumped.

Comment: actually I think I will just get the fields in a separate request like your answer suggests... the request will be small because I don't need any rows.